# check if attribute is existing

Tags: xpath, try-catch, repeater, xmldatasource

I am binding a repeater to XmlDataSource, binding an image source with a node value like below

```
<img src="<%# XPath("a:tags/a:tag[contains(@namespace, 'second_image')]", nsmgrdc).ToString() %>"
alt="<%# XPath("a:title",nsmgrdc)%>" />
```

but sometimes my XML doesn't have this node so i receive an error

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

is there a way i can check or do try, catch on the ItemTemplate level

Answer (score 0):

It's because of calling `ToString` method on null object. Simply use `XPath("a:tags/a:tag[contains(@namespace, 'second_image')]", nsmgrdc)` without calling `ToString`.